# Push Notifications with Flutter & Laravel

Tags: laravel, flutter, push-notification

Is it possible to send timely push notifications in Flutter with backend Laravel?
If Yes, please guide me through it.

Comment: Yes very much possible, try it out first then If a problem occurs stackoverflow community is here to help

Answer (score 0):

**You can use flutter local notification plugin**

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications